# Convert ticks to Datetime

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want to convert datetimeInTicks (long) into DateTime in U-sql. Something like this:

```
Select DateTime.Parse(LastModifiedUtcDateTimeTicks, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null) AS ProcessedTime FROM @extractVariable
```

Ofcourse, this will error out since the first parameter is expected to be a string. Is this conversion supported in U-sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Akos indicated you can pass ticks to the `DateTime` constructor then use the .net `ToString` method to format the string, eg

```
@output =
    SELECT new DateTime(LastModifiedUtcDateTimeTicks).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") AS ProcessedTime
    FROM @extractVariable;
```

Comment: Thanks!! :D Worked.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, U-SQL uses .NET types. .NET DateTime has a constructor that creates a DateTime from the ticks. Just a hunch, but this might work:

```
Select new DateTime(LastModifiedUtcDateTimeTicks) AS ProcessedTime FROM @extractVariable
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked. :) Accepting @wBob's answer for the formatting to string detail.